# Java: Compreender funcionamento wait() notify() notifyAll()

Tags: java

Estou estudando *Threads* Java e seus recursos e me deparei com uma dúvida.

Tenho as seguintes classes no meu programa:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized (b) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for complete b...");
                b.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Total: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}
```

`ThreadB`:

```
public class ThreadB extends Thread {

    int total;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                total += i;
            }

            notify(); //notifyAll();

            while(true) {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Executando este programa não consigo obter o comportamento que se espera do comando `notify()` quando adiciono o trecho de código abaixo em `ThreadB`:

```
 while(true) {
     //Do something
 }
```

Veja as saídas com e sem o trecho citado

[image: Execução Threads]

Vou ter que esperar acabar `ThreadB` mesmo `Main` sendo notificado de que o total já esta calculado?

Tem algo que possa ser feito para obter total sem que `ThreadB` finalize?

Antes de chegar aqui consultei esta [dúvida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999193/java-wait-notify-notifyall) com assunto similar de outro usuário.

Comment: Realmente isto não tem necessidade, vou editar. Obrigado pela observação.

Comment: O exemplo que citei é uma abstração do projeto que estou desenvolvendo. [Aqui](https://github.com/eduardoaw/simplesocketio/blob/master/src/io/github/eduardoaw/simplesocketio/control/ServerMode.java) e [aqui](https://github.com/eduardoaw/simplesocketio/blob/master/src/io/github/eduardoaw/simplesocketio/control/ClientThread.java) . No projeto tenho Thread de clientes socket sempre que aceito uma conexão, e basicamente dentro do while da thread, tenho um listener de socket. Tudo o que preciso é obter alguns atributos da thread criada assim que notify()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema não tem nada a ver com `wait` ou `notify`, mas com seus blocos `synchronized`.

Veja, o comportamento de blocos sincronizados é a garantia de que apenas uma *thread* por vez está executando para um dado objeto.

Bem, neste caso o laço `while(true)` no seu código faz com que sua *thread* permaneça eternamente no bloco sincronizado, fazendo com que a notificação enviada para a *thread* principal nunca entre realmente em vigor.

O que você precisa aprender de tudo isso é:

> Blocos sincronizados devem conter o mínimo de código possível

Em outras palavras, tudo o que você executa dentro de blocos sincronizados, embora seja *thread-safe*, bloqueia todo o resto do programa e frequentemente podem se tornar um gargalo. Além disso, blocos sincronizados podem levar a *deadlocks* se mau estruturados.

Resumo:

> Evite sincronização sempre que possível

Answer (score 3):

Apesar de achar a resposta suficiente, achei interessante sua pergunta e queria complementar com um exemplo prático - visto que você tem necessidades práticas, além das teóricas.

Uma grande vantagem de utilizar a linguagem Java é sua vasta API padrão, então um conselho é vá para a documentação sobre concorrência e descubra o quê a API Java já provê: [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Já me adiantei e fiz um protótipo funcional do seu código:

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Future<Integer> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new CallableB());

        int total = -1;

        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for complete b...");
            total = future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    }
}
```

CallableB.java (uma melhoria de ThreadB)

```
public class CallableB implements Callable<Integer> {

    private int total = -1;

    public CallableB() {
        // executa o runnable
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new RunnableB());
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        if (total == -1) {
            synchronized (this) {
                wait();
            }
        }

        return mTotal;
    }

    private class RunnableB implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int tmp = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                tmp += i;
            }

            total = tmp;

            synchronized (CallableB.this) {
                CallableB.this.notifyAll();
            }

            while(true) {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Na classe `Main`, chamo a classe `CallabelB` através de [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s.

Na classe `CallabelB` implemento a interface [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) que provê um `Runnable` com um retorno. Nela evoco o `RunnableB` que é a mesma implementação da `ThreadB`, entretanto utilizo o artifício da classe interna que pode acessar os membros da classe onde ela é contida.

Para gerir a concorrência utilizo tanto a sua abordagem inicial do `wait()` e `notifyAll()`, quanto a verificação da modificação da variável `total`.

Como `RunnableB` não possui condição de parada seu programa nunca termina, apesar da última linha do método `main` ser executada.

Depois também dê uma olhada em [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Espero ter te ajudado.

Obs: `CallableB.this` é o mecanismo para acessar a instância `this` da classe `CallableB` em `RunnableB`.

Comment: Exemplo interessante, mas tem algum motivo para criar dois `ExecutorService`s? Se colocar o conteúdo do método `run` no método `call` dá pra se livrar de uma boa parte do código.

Comment: Não, nenhum motivo. O `ExecutorService` da classe `CallableB` poderia ser substituido por `new RunnableB().run()`. Já colocar o conteúdo do método `run` no `call` não é possível, pois pelo o que entendi esse `Runnable` deve continuar sendo executado - mesmo após o cálculo de `total` - e o método `call` espera um retorno.

Comment: Olha aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html.